# Adding images to random divs each time

Tags: jquery, html

I asked this question but i made it to long and not specific enough so here it is again.

I am creating a game for fun that i found instructions how to do online. Where there are 12 cards with images facedown you click on 2 cards and if the images match they stay faced up and you win 2 points untill you find all the matches.

what i need to do is add each image to a random location, twice! i would need to generate random locations for each image and then add the images to the correct corresponding to that location in the page. You can think of the game board as a 4 x 3 grid. Each empty in a "row" gets one image.the problem i am having is that only 1 image is being choosen at random and not all 6 choosen twice at random

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26Pda/1/

here are the images :

```
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/cheese.gif
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/eggs.gif
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_blender.gif
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/tea.gif
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_collander.gif
http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_teapot.gif
```

here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery: Manipulating and Traversing Elements Project</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
div.container, div.row, form {
clear: both;
}
div.row > div {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 170px;
padding: 30px;
margin: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.row > div > img {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
bottom: 30px;
}
.visible {
 visibility: visible;
 }
 .hidden {
 visibility: hidden;
 }
.done {
visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="game.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
 <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <form>
 <input type="button" value="Play again">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle. You need to iterate the divs and append a random image to it instead of generating one random image and appending to all the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/jeBK2/. However, I don't think this is going to work for you. I would generate an array that has all the images twice, shuffle the array, then iterate the divs and array together, appending each image to the div.

Comment: thanks I am getting closer thanks to you guys the only problem is that the images are being added more than twice each image needs to be loaded exacly twice so that someone could match them. but thank you for the help

Comment: The last sentence of my comment addresses that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I would use:

http://jsfiddle.net/26Pda/6/

```
var images = ['...']; //your images above
var imagesused = [];
$('.container div:not(.row)').each(function() {
    var rand = Math.Floor(Math.Random() * images.length);
    $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
    if (imagesused.search(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
    else (imagesused.push(images[rand]);
});
```

What we're doing here is simple. We make an array to store which images we used. Then we iterate through each `<div>` that needs an image.

Then we pick a random image. This is done by choosing a random index of the `images` array. After that, we make a new `<img>` element and set its source to be that randomly chosen image.

Then we check to see if the image we used is in the `imagesused` array. If it already is, we remove that image from the array of images that can still be used. If it isn't, we add the image onto that array.

The reason we get two images (and not 1 or 3+) is because we use it once before it's been pushed onto the `imagesused` array, then when we use it the second time, we remove it from the `images` array, so it's no longer available for use. If we unconditionally removed it from the images array each iteration, then you'd only get to use it once.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting closer thanks to you guys the only problem is that the images are being added more than twice each image needs to be loaded exacly twice so that someone could match them.

Comment: Thank you man! I'm gonna study your code to understand what you did

Comment: I added some comments so you can understand it better.